# How to find SMTP port for a particular smtp.host?

Tags: java, smtp

How to find a smtp port for a particular smtp host?

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMailTLS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String username = "anthony.savarimut@slingmedia.com";
        final String password = "test";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.echostar.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "9000");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("AnthonyRajS@antony.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("antoalphi@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

is my code but it throws this exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at samples.SendMailTLS.main(SendMailTLS.java:47)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2153)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1912)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at samples.SendMailTLS.main(SendMailTLS.java:42)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:110)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:89)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2131)
```

I am sure that it gives problem in port. Please help me to go about this.

Regards
Tony

Comment: If you know the host to connect to, you *should* know the port as well. Otherwise it's like knowing what *street* someone lives on, but without knowing the house number.

Comment: Have you tried 25 and 50?  Those are some of the most common SMTP ports.

Comment: port  50 : Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.echostar.com, port: 50;

Comment: port 25 : No authentication mechansims supported by both server and client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default port for SMTP is 25:

http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/tips/mail-servers.html

My advice is that you contact the admin of the mail server.

Comment: helped, but is there any other way to find out the port no?

Comment: A port scan.  Generally considered impolite

Comment: Why do you not want to talk to the admin?  That's the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the admin for the port number. After trying 25,443,587 and failing so many times. My admin gave me 80 as the port number.